# Is there an easy way to create a variable which exists aufter session_destroy()?

Tags: php, variables, session

as is the question above, is there an easy way to create a variable that exists after session_destroy() ?
I already tried it in PHP with $Globals[''], but unfortunately it depends on $_Session[], which I have to destroy.

So now my question, is there a simple way to declare a variable that persists within the application ?

Comment: Can you explain more and provide some code regarding to your problem which you already try.

Comment: Variables are gone when the script ends. If you want to keep values, consider using memcached or redis.

Comment: Write to a file?

Comment: @MarkusZeller thanks, this is what i was loking to